# Cast DateTime to Unix Timestamp in Select statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, timestamp

I do have a database table with millions of archived value rows that consist of a value (single), two integer id fields, and a datetime field (and some other fields that are not relevant for the cache I want to build). The table structure is fixed, I can't change it. Now I want to read all rows into an array of objects of a simple class that I want to keep in memory for caching purposes.

In order to keep the memory consumption low, I want to use a unix timestamp instead of a datetime object. This is also useful because the frontend charts etc. that will consecutively work with this cache also natively work with Unix Timestamps.

For the cache creation I want to *select* directly into an *ArchiveElement*. This works well for most fields, but I don't know how to create a Unix Timestamp on the fly WITHIN the select statement:

```
ArchiveCache = db.ArchiveValues.Select(x => new ArchiveElement() {
    DataPointId = (UInt16)x.DataPointId,
    StationId = (UInt16)x.StationId,
    Value = (Single)x.Value,
    DateValue = x.DateValue // <-- Here I want to cast into Unix Timestamp
});
```

This is the ArchiveElement class:

```
public class ArchiveElement
{
    public UInt32 DateValue;
    public UInt16 DataPointId;
    public UInt16 StationId;
    public Single Value;
}
```

I do have a function in my application that can convert a `DateTime` into a Unix TimeStamp, but that does not work within the scope of the `select` statement. So I need to find another way.

One way would be to insert a `.ToList()` before the `.Select(..)` statement, so that I have access to my own function, but that would be an ugly workaround as it fetches a lot of unneccessary fields from the DB.

Is there a way to somehow convert the datetime "in place"?

Comment: Does it fetch a lot of unneccessary fields?  It looks like you're trying to pull the whole table anyways

Comment: The DB table has some more fields that I didn't mention here, just to keep it simple.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Unix timestamp? Do you mean the epoch time, for example 1423748783?

Comment: I mean seconds since Jan 1 1970. (All in UTC, conversion to local time happens later in the frontend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first you declare the Unix Epoch time:

```
var unixEpoch = DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Now in your `Select`, just subtract the epoch from your date value which gives a `TimeSpan` type from which you can get the `TotalSeconds` which is the value you need:

```
ArchiveCache = db.ArchiveValues.Select(x => new ArchiveElement() {
    DataPointId = (UInt16)x.DataPointId,
    StationId = (UInt16)x.StationId,
    Value = (Single)x.Value,
    DateValue = (x.DateValue - unixEpoch).TotalSeconds
});
```

**Note:** This assumes that your `DateValue` property is a double, you may need to cast it to a `long`.

**Edit**

To cope with Entity Framework, this may work:

```
ArchiveCache = db.ArchiveValues.Select(x => new ArchiveElement() {
    DataPointId = (UInt16)x.DataPointId,
    StationId = (UInt16)x.StationId,
    Value = (Single)x.Value,
    DateValue =  SqlFunctions.DateDiff("ss", unixEpoch, x.DateValue)
});
```

This may require a reference/import for `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer`.

Comment: That throws a System.ArgumentException (*DbArithmeticExpression*).

Comment: Ah, I forgot this was Entity Framework. You could do `ToList()` before the `Select`?

Comment: If I did so, I could use my own function as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, GETUTCDATE())
```

This will return the unix seconds in sql.